# Using IFERROR with overtime

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a document to work out over time.

On a time worked basis different jobs I do have different limits before reaching over time.

I have set up the form and it works great.

All for one thing it shows `####` instead of a `00:00` with my formula when no over time recorded.

```
=MAX(G11-(VLOOKUP(B11,$A$16:$C$21,3,)))
```

Is it possible to edit my code using `=IFERROR()` function or something else to show my desired time.

Comment: Are you missing something in your `MAX()`? Currently it looks like it's just calculating `TIME_WORKED - OVERTIME`, and you end up with `####` since that's what Excel does for negative times (i.e. you didn't work overtime). Maybe try `=MAX(G11-(VLOOKUP(B11,$A$16:$C$21,3,)),0)` to display `0` when the result is negative

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=IF()` to check if the value exists; and if so, then value is equal to `=MAX(G11-(VLOOKUP(B11,$A$16:$C$21,3,)))`, else is equal to `"NULL"`

Something like this:

```
=IF(IMPORTANT_CELL = "", "NULL", MAX(G11-(VLOOKUP(B11,$A$16:$C$21,3,))))
```

Or you can use `=IFERROR()` this way:

```
=IFERROR(MAX(G11-(VLOOKUP(B11,$A$16:$C$21,3,))), "NULL")
```